# Magento 1.9.0.1: way to override entire community module

Tags: magento, overriding

Is there a way to override an entire community module? I have a folder in app/code/community/something for a module called "something". What I want to achieve is that this module stays the same but I copy all files to app/code/local/something and make my modifications there. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As per my knowledge the community code cannot be overridden as you have proposed below.It works only for core .I think you need to create a custom module for this and need to override the community module in config.xml and  create your own php files extending the classes of community module accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen so far that we can override extensions from community to local codepool. You can extend classes of community module.

One possibility is that that you copy your `app/code/community/Vendor/Module` to `app/code/local/Vendor/Module` and update `Vendor_Module.xml` in `app/etc/modules` with `codePool` value as `local` instead of `community`.

Comment: actually I tried that but for some reason it didn't work... I don't understand why